# Using Chinese Remainder theorem to find number of solutions of modular exponentiation mod composite number

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, gcd-and-lcm, chinese-remainder-theorem

I am struggling to understand a simple fact that should follow from the Chinese remainder theorem. Suppose we have a system of equations.

$$
x^n = 1 (mod\ p)
$$
$$
x^n = 1 (mod\ q)
$$

Where $p, q$ are prime. I get the idea that each of these equations has a number of solutions $gcd(n, p-1), gcd(n, q-1)$ respectively due to the properties of cyclic fields (explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2549305/number-of-solutions-to-xn-equiv-1-mod-p)). I just don't get how we get that the number of solutions of $x^n = 1 (mod\ pq)$ is the multiple of the number of solutions to the other two equations. Meaning:
$$
gcd(n, p-1)*gcd(n, q-1)
$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It's like the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), because, by the CRT, each solution mod $pq$ corresponds to a solution mod $p$ and a solution mod $q$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The Chinese remainder theorem basically says that a variable $x$ ranging over residue classes modulo $pq$ can be thought of as two **independent** variables $y$ and $z$, one ranging over residue classes modulo $p$ and the other modulo $q$ such that $x\equiv y\pmod p$ as well as $x\equiv z\pmod q$.

Comment: May be you simply didn't take into account that when looking at the equation modulo $p$ your "universe" (=the set where your variables draw their values from) has size $p$, but in the combined congruence the universe has $pq$ elements, in a sense containing $q$ copies of each residue class modulo $p$, and also $p$ copies of each residue class modulo $q$?

Comment: See the Remarks in the linked dupes.